# Put Input value into php variable fails

Tags: php, html, session-variables

I´m trying to put an input value into a php variable so I can pass it to the next page via session.

This is my code:

Page 1:

```
 <?php
     session_start();
     if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
         $name = $_POST['Flightnumber1'];
         $_SESSION['Flightnumber'] = $name;
     };
 ?>
<form method="POST" action="CCPSeven.php">
<input name="Flightnumber1" />
<input name="Submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Page 2:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    $Flightnumber1 = $_SESSION['Flightnumber'];
    echo $Flightnumber1;
 ?>
```

For some reason it does not work, it does not show me any errors too.
I also can not open the debugger tool as it directly freezes firefox, so it´s status is "(Not Responding)".

Please help.

Comment: Do you have any whitespace (spaces/new lines) before the `<?php`? Also: Try chrome for debugging. You're going to have a much better time.

Comment: If you have whitespace causing headers to be sent before you start your session and error reporting is off or turned too low this will fail silently

Comment: There's nothing on your form named submit.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'm assuming he didn't include his submit button

Comment: @FrankerZ , No I even put it directly on top of the code

Comment: From what I see in your code, it's indented slightly (With 1 space before it)

Comment: @JohnConde Error reporting is on

Comment: Is the code being run? Check to make sure you're in the `if` block of code

Comment: Error reporting is on, but is it set to report all errors?

Comment: At the very top of the file (Before `session_start()`), put the following: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1'); ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');`, and run the script again.

Comment: @FrankerZ I'm just going by what I can see. Without the submit button included, there's no way to tell whether or not it has `name="Submit"`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic , Oh i forgot give me a sec

Comment: @Don'tPanic How does he even submit that form?

Comment: @FrankerZ you can submit a form by pressing Enter.

Comment: @FrankerZ forgot to add submit button, just added it in my question

Comment: Okay, never mind that, then. Sorry for the tangent.

Comment: btw maybe it helps, if I pass simple strings the session works, so it´s about the value and variable

Comment: Is Page1 CCPSeven.php?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, no it page 2

Comment: So the form posts to page 2, but the code that handles the post is on page 1?

Comment: @FrankerZ I tried your error reporting, nothing showing

Comment: Then simply put, your code isn't being executed. That code *should* work fine, assuming that `isset($_POST['Submit'])` is true, and `$_POST['Flightnumber1']` is your value. Make sure you're submitting to the correct screen, debug with print_r(), ie `print_r($_POST)`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic The code that handles the post is on page 2, I´m just trying to post the session to next page, it works with simple 'strings' but not with variables :(

Comment: @FrankerZ can I message you in 10 minutes ?